# Why easier to numerically minimize than to maximize a function

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

Is it easier, in terms of coputational complexity or speed, to numerically minimize a function $f$ than to maximize $-f$? Why is that so? I have noticed that most optimization algorithms in Matlab are written to minimize the input, and I have been told that it is indeed more efficient to do so.

Comment: It is not more efficient. If you have an algorithm to solve $\min f\left(X\right)$,
you have an algorithm to solve $\max-f\left(X\right)$.

Comment: Who told you that? In other terms, what is the value of the source who told you that it is more efficient?

Comment: @par We do not have an algorithm to solve $min f(x)$. What we have is methods for numerically estimating it.

Comment: The only "extra cost" may come from the need to multiply each evaluation of $f$ by $-1$. However, I doubt that this "increase" of the computational complexity would be measurable.

Answer (score 5):

What was told to you is simply nonsense. As given in the comment by par, maximization is the mirror of minimization with respect to multiplication by $-1$. The function does not get any simpler or more complex by multiplying it by $-1$. Therefore maximization and minimization are of equivalent complexity.

Comment: We do not have an algorithm to solve $min f(x)$. What we have is methods for numerically estimating it.

Comment: @Studenttea it doesnt matter. One can always find another version of the same numerical method such that it will solve the equivalent maximization problem on average in the same time. For example consider particle filters.